# MPI ranks forking a process

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I am implementing a workflow and a part of that workflow is to call a python script and within that python script let each rank run an executable or python program.

So to test that I wrote a simple program but it does not work properly. The code is described below:

**helloworld.py**

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import sys
import subprocess

mpi_warn_on_fork = 0

size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
name = MPI.Get_processor_name()

for i in range(size):
  if rank == i:
    command = "python hello.py %d %d %s" % (rank, size, name)
    subprocess.call("command", shell = True)
```

hello.py

```
import sys
print "Hello from rank = %s of %s on host %s" %(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
```

And I call the program by using:
mpirun -np 16 python helloworld.py

But this implementation is not working as only one rank out of 16 forks a process with mpirun runtime generating warning message regarding usage of fork in the program.

Can someone please recommend some thing such that I can allow every MPI rank to execute a shell command properly.

**EDIT:**
Suggestions for implementing this idea in C/C++ will also work.

Comment: Don't use `shell = True`; just write `subprocess.check_call(["python","hello.py",str(rank),str(size),name])`.

Comment: If you don't really need to operate with communicators before running the command, you can even use Python without MPI library or even a shell script to execute the MPI program.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot quote `"command"` in the last line of `helloworld.py` (it is a variable, not a string).

```
command = "python hello.py %d %d %s" % (rank, size, name)
subprocess.call(command, shell = True)
```